# React Native Null is not an object (evaluating 'RNInstalledApplication.getApps')

Tags: react-native

I'm new in React Native and I don't understand how I can fix this error :

**Null is not an object (evaluating 'RNInstalledApplication.getApps')**

The package is in my node_modules folder and I linked it.

My code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import RNInstalledApplication from 'react-native-installed-application';
 
const Applies = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 
  const getApplication = ()=>{
    RNInstalledApplication.getApps()
    .then(apps => {
      setData(apps)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
 
  return (
    <View style={{ marginVertical: 80, marginHorizontal: 20 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> getApplication()}>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Applies;
```

And

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Applies from './components/Applies';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Applies />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Can you help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try console log the apps object - see what that returns as the null may be referring that you are setting a null object.

```
const getApplication = ()=>{
    RNInstalledApplication.getApps()
    .then(apps => {
      console.log('Found apps: ', apps); 
      
      if(!apps) {
        setData(apps)
      }
      else {
        console.log('No apps found')
     }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I got the same error. When I tried to link the package I got this : warn Calling react-native link [packageName] is deprecated in favor of autolinking. It will be removed in the next major release.
Autolinking documentation: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
(node:15572) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: As it says - it's possible the package is quite old and becoming deprecated so may not work as expected.  Have you tried:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-installed-apps

Comment: I don't understand why I still get an error when I run this command: 
react-native link
(node:15948) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

I just generate a project, try npm install and run react-native link

Comment: I also try the package that you say I get a similar error : 
react-native link react-native-android-installed-apps
warn Calling react-native link [packageName] is deprecated in favor of autolinking. It will be removed in the next major release.
Autolinking documentation: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
(node:15972) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: Well the package I sent is only Android - hence the name. If you are looking for an iOS one, have a look at this: https://github.com/dimapaloskin/react-native-installed-apps

Comment: There does not seem to be a package that works for both Android and iOS - so you may need to use 2 for either OS's, at first glance anyhow.